# Methods called within __new__

Tags: python

I would like to create a class which returns an int when initiated, like so:

```
r = Foo(10)
print r # 1000
```

I know you can do this by overriding the `__new__` method. However I need it to also execute other class functions within the `__new__` method, how do I do this?

So far I have:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, i):
        cls.i = i
        return cls.foo_fun()

    def foo_fun(self):
        return self.i * 100
print Foo(5)
```

and the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
return cls.foo_fun()
TypeError: unbound method foo_fun() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: Does changing it to `return cls.foo_fun(self)` (or `foo_fun(cls)`) work?

Comment: note that just using `cls` instead of `self` doesn't make this a class method, you will need to use the [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator (In which case I don't think that `__new__` can be a class method).

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why not use a factory function?

Comment: you could also just simply subclass `int`, then your object would look like an int and act like an int...

Comment: You don't have an instance in your `__new__` factory method (which is static, really). You don't *have* a `self` to call things on. Use another static on class method.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have confused C++/Java new for Python `__new__`. The instance creation method in Python is `__init__` and by the time you need to muck with `__new__`  you'll know the difference. Beginners almost never have cause to define `__new__`.

Comment: @msw: but if this was an actual subclass of an immutable type (like `int`) then you'd have to use `__new__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are, per usual, technically correct. Given the level of Python questions by the OP, I suspect a simpler misunderstanding,

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an instance in your `__new__` factory method (which is static, really). You don't *have* a `self` to call things on. Use another static or class method:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, i):
        return cls.foo_fun(i)

    @staticmethod
    def foo_fun(i):
        return i * 100

print Foo(5)
```

Setting `cls.i` is not thread-safe as that state is shared between all `__new__` calls; you are much better off passing along the value as a parameter to another method.

However, you are abusing classes here; you never create an instance of this class, there is no way to use the class in `isinstance()` type checks, etc. Just use a factory function:

```
def foo(i):
    return i * 100
```

If you really meant for this to be a subclass of `int`, you'll still need to create an actual instance of your class to return:

```
class Foo(int):
    def __new__(cls, i):
        i = int(i)  # ensure you have an actual integer first
        value = cls.foo_fun(i)
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, value)

    @staticmethod
    def foo_fun(i):
        return i * 100
```

The above inherits from `int`, handles the case where the argument is not an integer (`like`"42"`, a string convertible to an integer) and returns an instance of your class.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(int):
...     def __new__(cls, i):
...         i = int(i)  # ensure you have an actual integer first
...         value = cls.foo_fun(i)
...         return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, value)
...     @staticmethod
...     def foo_fun(i):
...         return i * 100
... 
>>> f = Foo(42)
>>> f
4200
>>> isinstance(f, Foo)
True
>>> Foo("42")  # non-integer input works too
4200
```